# How to change rules for the hidraw0 device?

Tags: command-line

I am tying to connect Polar Flow with Ubuntu19. The Polar flow works with [Wine](https://www.reddit.com/r/Polarfitness/comments/etqrv3/polar_flow_sync_on_linux/). However, Ubuntu does not recognize the USB connection (my Polar m400).

I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1061848/909796) and got to the point 11 with no problems but then the point 12: there is no change in the `hidraw0`. It is grand to root only. I wonder what am I doing wrong? Is this correct: `KERNEL=="hidraw*", SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", MODE="0664", GROUP="dialout"`

Did some more trying, and I succeeded to change it (I typed "ls -l /dev/" and saw dialout as Group by hidraw0 )

---

However. when I wrote "dmesg | grep -i usb" I got:

`[   71.467633] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[   71.481418] hid-generic 0003:0DA4:0008.0001: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Polar Electro Oy Polar M400] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input0`

So, something is still wrong. Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: @Andreas 1312 ?

Comment: There is nothing Kubuntu-specific about that answer. it should work on all flavors of Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

my hidraw0 is also showing root, after editing the sudo vi hid.rules

crw-------  1 root     root    240,   0 Mär 16 15:29 hidraw0

trying to polarflow watch to sync.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1287517)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).